# What is .divClicked here?

Tags: jquery

What is .divClick here ??

```
$("div#div1").bind("click.divClick",function(){alert("Div Clicked");})
```

some one ask me this question and i have no answer for that. is it event type or namespace ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is namespace. If the eventType string contains a period (.) character, then the event is namespaced. The period character separates the event from its namespace. For example, in the call .bind('click.name', handler), the string click is the event type, and the string name is the namespace. Namespacing allows us to unbind or trigger some events of a type without affecting others. See the discussion of .unbind() for more information.

Answer (score 8):

Events in jQuery can be written like this:

```
<event-type>[.<event-namespace>]
```

In your case, `click.divClick` is just a `click` event, except that it's organized in the `divClick` namespace.

One advantage of using namespaces is when you need to unbind event listeners:

```
$(el).bind('click', function() { alert('click 1'); };
$(el).bind('click.divClick', function() { alert('click 2'); };

$(el).unbind('click.divClick');
```

The last line will unregister only the `click 2` event handler without affecting the `click 1` event handler.

You can also unregister all events from a namespace:

```
$(el).unbind('.divClick');
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a custom event.

You can call it like

```
$('mySelector').trigger("click.divClick");
```

Please see the docs: [jQuery `.bind()` Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)